# where can i download onivim

Tags: downloads, vim

I am thinking of trying onivim.
I visited their page and read the installation guide.
They guide me to download the app image but there was no link in the page.
Where can I download the app image?

Comment: Can you include those links by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1379357/edit) the question?

Comment: You know that software isn't released yet right ?

Comment: You need to order it or become a patron to download the appimage

Answer (score 1):

In their page it says:

> Download

> Early access builds are available to patrons or users who have pre-ordered:

> Don't have a license key yet? Become a patron!

So... are you a patron?